# In Keras, how to use dot() to calculate cosine proximity between a tensor and each row of a constant matrix?

Tags: python, keras

I have a tensor `jdes` which is `(?, 100)` and a matrix of constants `jt_six` that has shape `(6,100)`. And I'm trying to get a result of the cosine proximity of `jdes` and each row of `jt_six` and the result should have shape `(?, 6)`. I saw that `dot()` layer is able to calculate the cosine proximity setting `normalize=True` but with the code I have, I get a result with shape `(6,1)` which doesn't have batch size in it. Can anyone help me with it?

```
def dot_similarity(jdes):
    jdes = K.l2_normalize(jdes, axis=-1) # (?, 100)
    jt_six = K.l2_normalize(K.variable(jt_six), axis=-1) # (6, 100)
    return dot([jt_six, jdes], axes=-1, normalize=True) # (6, 1), need (?, 6)

result = Lambda(dot_similarity)(jdes)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `K.dot()` directly. Because you already use `K.l2_normalize`, the result of matrix multiplication is cosine proximity.

```
from keras.models import Model
import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import Lambda,Input
import numpy as np

N = 100
def dot_similarity(jdes):
    jdes = K.l2_normalize(jdes, axis=-1) # (?, 100)
    # define it myself
    jt_six = K.constant(np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(6, N)))
    jt_six = K.l2_normalize(K.variable(jt_six), axis=-1) # (6, 100)
    return K.dot(jdes,K.transpose(jt_six))

jdes = Input(shape=(N,))
result = Lambda(dot_similarity)(jdes)
model = Model(jdes,result)
print(model.summary())

_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 100)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
lambda_1 (Lambda)            (None, 6)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```